# HTML-encode special characters for JSON serialization

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a web service that sends and accepts JSON, and handles all special characters by HTML-encoding them.  I can parse and read the web service data perfectly fine using the following (error checking removed for brevity):

```
cleanJsonString = [self stringByDecodingXMLEntities:jsonString];
NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [cleanJsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]
                                                         options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                           error: &parseError];
```

The problem comes into play when I need to serialize user input to send data back to the server.  I'm currently using the following:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDictionaryObject
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&parseError];
    NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

The problem is that this does not account whatsoever for special characters.  No errors occur on the client side, but the web service is receiving bad data.  I know I could brute force it by recursing the dictionary object and encoding every string before serializing.  But would it be safe to just do one single encode operation on the entire JSON string without corrupting it?  Or, even more ideally, is there such a parameter that would handle encoding during the serialization process.  Any advice or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: JSON strings (including both object key values and string literals) are interpreted as UTF8 and can include any legal "special character" without escaping, save for quote and backslash.  If the encoded JSON is sent through a channel that needs further escaping, that should be done after encoding and undone before decoding.passing the data to NSJSONSerialization.

Comment: In the above second case you do not appear to be using any escaping, but are simply converting the JSON from NSData to NSString.  This will be fine for some protocols, but not for those which must have certain characters escaped.  If stringByDecodingXMLEntities is working in one direction, it seems possible that stringByEncodingXMLEntities might work in the other.

Comment: I've given it a try with stringByEncodingXMLEntities on the resulting JSON string, but I had to first do a temporary replace of double-quotes and then put them back after encoding.  Otherwise the JSON becomes corrupted.  Is there more robust way to do this, perhaps specifying some other encoding parameter during the NSData to NSString conversion?

Comment: Whatever you do needs to mirror what's going on on the other end.  Ask the site owner what encoding is used.